# Call different methods for onResume , onStart etc in Tabs

Tags: android

I am using 5 tabs. When I move to some tab first time, every method is called given in onCreate. But When I press again the same tab, already loaded view is showed. I want some methods to be called every tome I press the tab button. How do I do that?
Second I use this method:`

```
TabHost tabHost =  (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
```

To come to some tab, I want some methods to be called and some should not be. How do I get that?
In iOS I have methods like viewDidAppear, viewDidLoad, etc. So I got my task done. But in android I can not achieve this. Here is code and explanation:

```
public class Help extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help);
    showPopover();
    loadImages();

}
public void showPopover(){
      Log.d(getClass().getName(), "This is popover " );
}
public void loadImages(){
      Log.d(getClass().getName(), "This is image " );
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

When I press help tab button, both method should called every time.
When I come from some other tab to help tab, only loadImages should be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main tab activity create 5 static Boolean variables each of one activity
Initialize with all with false
In you other child activities `onCreate()` method change this to true;
In `onResume()` check status of these Boolean values and as per value run methods you want